# Test flight fails to detect the OS of an iPad when I try to install my app build using test flight

Tags: testflight

I have a app to test which requires iOS 8.1 to run, so I updated my device from iOS 8 to iOS 8.1.1.
But my test flight still says "Your device is running iOS 8.0, but this build requires iOS 8.1"

Comment: Same issue for me, testflight tells me "Your device is running iOS 7.1.2, but this build requires iOS 8.0" yet I am running iOS 8

Comment: I have tried iPhonr 4S and iPod 5th gen. Tried completely removing Testflightapp app and profiles and re-installing. Still wrongly identifying my iOS version as 7 instead of 8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the little settings button, then devices, then click to ‘reconnect current device’ and then it will update your OS as far as test flight is concerned once you finish reconnecting the device. At least we can take pleasure in knowing that TestFlight as we know it won't be around for long...sigh